# How to create a builder for third party POJO?

Tags: java, lombok

How can I create a Lombok builder for a third party class (i.e. I cannot modify its source code)?

I have an existing class that I cannot change:

```java
public class ThirdPartyPojo {
    // one of many properties
    private String name;

    public ThirdPartyPojo() {
        // default no-args constructor
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // many more getters and setters
}
```

Now I would like to create a `@Builder` so that I get a fluent builder API to simplify instantiation of `ThirdPartyPojo` with default values.

This is what I tried:

```java
@Builder
public class ThirdPartyPojoBuilder extends ThirdPartyPojo {

    @Default
    private String name = "default name";

    // many more default values for other properties
}
```

The code compiles and I am able to reference the builder, e.g.

```java
ThirdPartyPojo pojoWithDefaultName = ThirdPartyPojoBuilder.builder().build();
ThirdPartyPojo pojoWithCustomName = ThirdPartyPojoBuilder.builder().name("custom name").build();

System.out.println(pojoWithDefaultName.getName());
System.out.println(pojoWithCustomName.getName());
```

However, this does not work as `getName()` returns `null` for both `pojoWithDefaultName` and `pojoWithCustomName`.

Comment: Try add `@Builder  and @Data  ( @Setter , @Getter )` on entity

Comment: @DilermandoLima Can you please elaborate? Do you suggest that I add those annotations to the `ThirdPartyPojo`? This is an external dependency so I cannot modify its source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [pirho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70353801/303598), I found a feasible solution that also honors default values.

1. Extend the third party class
2. Add the `@Builder` annotation on class level
3. Add any fields that should be configurable by the builder
4. Add `@Default` and assign values to any fields that should have a default value
5. Add a constructor with all parameters matching all fields
6. Add `this.set*(...)` for each constructor parameter

e.g.

```java
@Builder
public class ThirdPartyPojoBuilder extends ThirdPartyPojo {
    @Default
    private String name = "default name" 

    public ThirdPartyPojoBuilder(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }
}
```

which also supports default values:

```
ThirdPartyPojo pojoWithDefaultName = ThirdPartyPojoBuilder.builder().build();
ThirdPartyPojo pojoWithCustomName = ThirdPartyPojoBuilder.builder().name("custom name").build();

System.out.println(pojoWithDefaultName.getName()); // prints "default name"
System.out.println(pojoWithCustomName.getName());  // prints "custom name"
```

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid there is no easy way out to have Lombok automagically generate builder the way you might want. What [Lombok @Builder](https://www.projectlombok.org/features/Builder) does in general is:

> Finally, applying @Builder to a class is as if you added @AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE) to the class and applied the @Builder annotation to this all-args-constructor.

So that is - I think - all that you can do:

```
public class ThirdPartyPojoBuilder extends ThirdPartyPojo {
    @Builder
    public ThirdPartyPojoBuilder(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }
}
```

Then it is possible - for example:

```
var thirdPartyPojo = ThirdPartyPojoBuilder.builder().name("A Name").build();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works in case `name()` is explicitly set. However, it does not seem to honor `@Default`? Executing just 

    `var thirdPartyPojo = ThirdPartyPojoBuilder.builder().build();`

result in `name == null` despite that I have configured

    `@Default private String name = "default name";`

Comment: I found a solution by moving the `@Builder` annotation from the constructor to the class level, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70360292/303598)

Comment: @matsev Sorry, missed the default value somehow but glad this helped.